# How to force marathon to redo the deployment of an already running container with the existing version `:latest`?

Tags: mesos, marathon

I am trying to deploy to marathon an image already deployed and running.

The version used for this image is `:latest`.

The deployment is happening every two week, but marathon fail to reinstall the application because it does not see any configuration change.

I have tried to add `forcePullImage: true` to the json deployment plan but that didn't help.

Is it possible to force marathon to accept the deployment event if the configuration hasn't changed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the configuration hasn't changed only way to force application to reload is restart.